# Complex tabular layout

Tags: tables

I am trying to understand what the following line implies for a tabular and did not find anything matching it:
`\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{@{}p{184pt}@{}|}}`

- What is the `*{2}` for?
- What is the `@{}` for?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should read a book on LaTeX tables ;-) Shortly said, it defines 2 table columns with parbox width of 184 pt, with vertical lines and no space between cell content and the vertical lines (i.e. `\tabcolsep` is effectively `0pt`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The `*{2}{...}` will replicate the content of the column specification `{...}` twice

  If there are, say 10 columns, it is quicker to write `\begin{tabular}{*{10}{l}}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}`. Both will provide a table with 10 left aligned column content.
- `@{}` will remove the space between the vertical line `|` and the true cell content. Since there are two of such spaces, both `@{}` to the left and to right have to specified, if it should be removed.  This is a better alternative to `\setlength{\tabcolsep{0pt}`, see also [Unwanted padding in tabular columns when cells contain multiple rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195899/unwanted-padding-in-tabular-columns-when-cells-contain-multiple-rows/195902#195902).

  Normally `\tabcolsep` defaults to `6pt`

Comment: Ok, thank you. How can I automatically center the content of the tabular cells with such a definition, please?

Comment: @wipman: Centering horizontally? `\begin{tabular}{*{2}{c}}` for example

Comment: @wipman: Does my proposition answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it does, but as soon as I try to change the dimensions of my `tabular`, the centering applies no more, and the `headers` keep their former position (the one set with: `\begin{tabular}{*{2}{c}}`).

Comment: @wipman: Please post an example into your question above, as it's hard to guess what might go wrong