# What is the use of @{}?

Tags: tables, formatting

Can someone explain the use of `@{}` in table formatting as in:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}cp{0.45\columnwidth}p{0.25\columnwidth}@{}}
```

Comment: `@{}` will remove the `\tabcolsep` that exists between columns. In this case before first column and after last column. `\tabcolsep` is the horizontal separation between columns.

Comment: @HarishKumar Either find a dup or answer the question.

Comment: @karlkoeller It is easy to answer than finding a dup :)

Comment: related: [Question about @{} used in array environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207457/579)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The text inside a column of the `tabular` is padded, on both sides, with `\tabcolsep`. When we put `@{}`, this space is removed. See the following figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
  With \verb|@{}| on both ends:

  \medskip

  \begin{tabular}{|@{}p{0.45\columnwidth}|p{0.45\columnwidth}@{}|}
   \lipsum[2]  & \lipsum*[2]
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip
  Without \verb|@{}| on both ends:
  \medskip

  \begin{tabular}{|p{0.45\columnwidth}|p{0.45\columnwidth}|}
   \lipsum[2]  & \lipsum*[2]
   \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 13):

As Harish says, the `@{}` removes the inter-column space. The reason the syntax is as it is
with `{}` is that the argument is text that is typeset between each cell. If you have a column specification of `cc@{hello}cc`  then you have a 4 column table with the word `hello` instead of space between columns 2 and 3.