# Line not equal length in table using cmidrule (tabularx)

Tags: tables, tabularx

I found that the line is not the equal length in second row and the first row. Is it possible to make it same line length.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}           % Load package caption for decent foramtting and spacing
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}       % Use booktabs rules and get rid og vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt}          % Both line necessary for decent spacing, unless you are using booktabs rules.
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}


\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{A}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=0\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=0.65\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}
\begin{table}[!ht]

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}A*{5}{B}@{}}
    \toprule
     & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{ATest Combination}} \\
     \cmidrule(lr){3-5}
     & & \small Mean (\%)
     & \small Std. Deviation (\%)& \small Std. Error Mean(\%) \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pair 1} & Transpor Example Dataset (AA) - Transpor Example Dataset (BB) 
    & 312314.20\% & 321321.36\% & 4.321354\%  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{dsadsa dsadasd%
    \label{tab:test123}% 
    }  
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

The outcome:

[image]

And also, how to make the outcome of the word in whole words without being break out automaticall using '-'?

For example:

```
Transpor Example 
Dataset (AA) - 
Transpor Example 
Dataset (BB)
```

and not

```
Transpor Exam-
ple Data -
set (AA) - 
Trans- 
por Example 
Dataset (BB)
```

Comment: Regarding the horizontal line: replace `\cmidrule(lr){3-5}` with `\cmidrule(l){3-5}` or (`\cmidrule{3-5}`)

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. It works. Between, what is the meaning of `lr` and `l` in this part? Any source for reading this, cannot find it.

Comment: `r` = shorten the line on the right, `l`= shorten the line on the left. This is especially useful if you have more than one `cmidrule` next to each other. Without the `lr` two adjacent cmidrules would appear as one line instead of two. For a more in depth description, please see page 4 of the `booktabs` manual.

Comment: Could you please expllain the purpose of the `A` type column in your table?

Comment: @leandriis. Actually, i just copy from the references code for `{@{}A*{5}{B}@{}}` and I still cannot figure out the meaning in whole. So, i just edit `hsize=0` to look more nice in output table.
`\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}A*{5}{B}@{}}` = `\begin{tabular}[pos]{cols}` and I checked https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables. Not sure why `[pos]` can be `{\testwidth}`.

Comment: You seem to mix up the `tabular` and `tabularx` environments. Also, I don't think that the `A` and `B` columns are really useful in your table, so  I have replaced them in my answer with a more suitable choice.

Comment: Regarding the meaning of `{@{}A*{5}{B}@{}}`  you might want to hava a look at: [What is the use of @{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233938/134144), [Repeating the same column type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233601/134144), [Table layout with tabularx (column widths: 50%|25%|25%)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84400/134144)  and [How does the \newcolumntype command work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/257128/134144)

Comment: @leandriis, thanks. I need some time to digest it all. Between can I save this post and come back later to read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three different versions of your table:

In all of the following example, I have corrected the trimming commands of the `cmidrule` command (`(lr)`, `(l)`, `(r)`, For a detailed explanation please see page 4 of the `booktabs` manual.)

In the first example, I have also replaced the column specifiers `{@{}A*{5}{B}@{}}` by the more reasonable `{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}`.

In the second table, I have alternatively used `S` type columns from the `siunitx` package in order to allow the numbers to be centered with respect to their decimal separator. Additionally, I have removed repeated `%` signs that are superfluous since they are already mentioned in the column headers.

In the last example, I have used a slightly smaller font size and decreased the horizontal white space between adjacent columns. With this, the contents of the second column can even fit into two lines instead of 4.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx, caption}
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e}

\usepackage{makecell,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{ATest Combination}} \\
     \cmidrule{3-5}
     & & \small Mean (\%)
     & \makecell{\small Std. Deviation\\ (\%)}& \makecell{\small Std. Error \\ Mean (\%)} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pair 1} & Transpor Example Dataset (AA) - Transpor Example Dataset (BB) 
    & 312314.20\% & 321321.36\% & 4.321354\%  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{dsadsa dsadasd%
    \label{tab:test123}% 
    }  
\end{table}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}XS[table-format=6.2]S[table-format=6.2]S[table-format=1.6]}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ATest Combination} \\
     \cmidrule{3-5}
     & &  {Mean (\%)}
     & {\makecell{ Std. Deviation\\ (\%)}}& {\makecell{ Std. Error \\ Mean (\%)}} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pair 1} & Transpor Example Dataset (AA) - Transpor Example Dataset (BB) 
    & 312314.20 & 321321.36 & 4.321354  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{dsadsa dsadasd%
    \label{tab:test123}% 
    }  
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xccc}
    \toprule
    & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{ATest Combination} \\
     \cmidrule{3-5}
     & &  Mean (\%)
     & \makecell{ Std. Deviation\\ (\%)}& \makecell{ Std. Error \\ Mean (\%)} \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Pair 1} & Transpor Example Dataset (AA) - Transpor Example Dataset (BB) 
    & 312314.20 & 321321.36 & 4.321354  \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\caption{dsadsa dsadasd%
    \label{tab:test123}% 
    }  
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. It is possible to `bold` the words in first 2 example? `& \makecell{\small Std. Deviation\\ (\%)}& \makecell{\small Std. Error \\ Mean (\%)} \\` . I had tried to `& \makecell{\small {\textbf{std. Deviation}}\\ \{\textbf{(\%)}}& \makecell{\small {\textbf{Std. Error}}} \\ {\textbf{Mean (\%)}} \\` .But it seemed not working.

Comment: @aan, in table you shpuld instead `\makecell`  use `\thead` and in preamble define `\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}`.

Comment: @Zarko, thanks. Is it means that we created a new command name `\thead` OR put `\small` into `\threadfont`?

Comment: @ann: No, the `\thead`command  is defined by the `makecell` package (intended for columns heads), as it is  `\makecell` command.