# Symbollist not left aligned

Tags: lists, environments, longtable, glossaries

Refer to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447208/ordered-symbols-list-with-units), I try to adapt my list of symbols to my list of abbreviations.

**List of abbreviations**

```
% Setup list of abbreviations
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\vspace{-3mm}\begin{longtable*}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}{\end{longtable*}}}

\printglossary[style=mylong,type=\acronymtype,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]
```

[image: List of abbreviations]

Now I would like to achieve a quite similar presentation for my list of symbols.

**List of symbols**

```
\newglossary{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{}
\glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{
\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\vspace{-3mm}
\begin{longtable*}[l]{lp{\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}}{\end{longtable*}}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryunit{##1}\\
}
}

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=symbunitlong,title=Symbolverzeichnis]
```

[image: List of symbols]

How to left align the list of symbols and how to adapt the distance between my symbols to the distance from CAD to CRC?

**EDIT1**

To solve the problem with the vertical distance I have just to add a sort property to the definition of a new symbol like this:

```
\glsxtrnewsymbol[
description={test1},
unit={m},
sort={a}]
{y}{y}
```

Thanks to @leandriis for more information see this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129294/how-do-i-remove-alphabetical-grouping-of-acronyms-in-the-list).

**EDIT2**

If I change the line to this like mentioned of @leandriis

```
\begin{longtable*}[l]{@{}lp{\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}}{\end{longtable*}}
```

It seems to be better but not perfect

[image]

**EDIT3**

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[binary-units=true,locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,symbols,nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

% Setup list of abbreviations
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
  \setglossarystyle{long}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
    \vspace{-3mm}%
    \begin{longtable*}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\tabcolsep-2cm}@{}}%
  }{\end{longtable*}}
}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym[
plural={Test},
firstplural={Test (Test)},
description={Test}]
{Test}{Test}{Test}

\newacronym[
plural={Test1},
firstplural={Test1 (Test1)},
description={Test1}]
{Test1}{Test1}{Test1}

% Setup list of symbols
\newglossary{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{}
\glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{
\setglossarystyle{long3col}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{\vspace{-3mm}\begin{longtable*}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}}{\end{longtable*}}

\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryunit{##1}\\
}
}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[
description={test0},
unit={m},
sort={a}]
{x}{x}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[
description={test1},
unit={m},
sort={a}]
{y}{y}

\makeglossaries

\glsadd{x}
\glsadd{y}
\glsadd{Test}
\glsadd{Test1}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mylong,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=symbunitlong,title=Symbolverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

*RESULT*

[image]
[image]

Comment: The vertical spacing between the shown entries might be due to grouping with redard to the first letter. See here: [How do I remove alphabetical grouping of acronyms in the list?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129294/134144)

Comment: To remove the horizontal indentation, you could add `@{}` to `{lp{\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}}` as follows: `{@{}lp{\glsdescwidth}>{\arraybackslash}p{1cm}}}` (See also [What is the use of @{}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233938/134144))

Comment: Due to the lack of a complete MWE my above comments were just pure guesses. Could you therefore please edit your question to include  a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't guess the width and redefine the left distance:

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[binary-units=true,locale = DE]{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[nonumberlist,acronym,toc,symbols,nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\usepackage{showframe} % just for the example

% Setup list of abbreviations
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
  \setglossarystyle{long}
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
    \vspace{-3mm}%
    \begin{longtable*}{
      @{}
      p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}
      p{\dimexpr\textwidth-\tabcolsep-2cm}
      @{}
    }%
  }{\end{longtable*}}
}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

% Setup list of symbols
\newglossary{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{}
\glsaddstoragekey{unit}{}{\glsentryunit}
\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{
  \setglossarystyle{long3col}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{%
    \vspace{-3mm}%
    \setlength{\LTleft}{0pt}%
    \begin{longtable*}{%
      @{}
      p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}
      p{\glsdescwidth}
      r
      @{}
    }%
  }{\end{longtable*}}
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} & \glossentrydesc{##1} & \glsentryunit{##1}\\
  }%
}

\newacronym[
plural={Test},
firstplural={Test (Test)},
description={Test}]
{Test}{Test}{Test}

\newacronym[
plural={Test1},
firstplural={Test1 (Test1)},
description={Test1}]
{Test1}{Test1}{Test1}


\glsxtrnewsymbol[
description={test0},
unit={m},
sort={a}]
{x}{x}

\glsxtrnewsymbol[
description={test1},
unit={m},
sort={a}]
{y}{y}

\makeglossaries

\glsadd{x}
\glsadd{y}
\glsadd{Test}
\glsadd{Test1}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,style=mylong,title=Abkürzungsverzeichnis]

\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=symbunitlong,title=Symbolverzeichnis]
\end{document}
```

Don't forget `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is located in the list of symbols not in the list of abbreviations.

Comment: @Passe Similar to the above

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks you!